# Workday Rest API - WQL

Tags: workday-api

I am new to Workday and the REST API and I keep running into walls with the most basic things.

I am trying to access the /data endpoint and use this with simple WQL query. My issue is I get a not found:

```
{
"error": "not found: data",
"code": "S21"
}
```

This is my basic query endpoint:

https://wd2-impl-services1.workday.com/ccx/api/v1/myredactedorgname/data?query=SELECT worker from allWorkers

My other basic API calls are returning data...this one says "not found"

My admins don't really seem to know and the I can't really find anything clearly in the documentation. If it was permissions, I would think I would get an unauthorized error, not a 404. Is there something I could be missing or something that needs to be enabled?

Thank you all for your help. I hope to unstuck this thing soon!

Answer (score 1):

I was also having this issue, and while studying the swagger file provided in the Workday Docs for the /data endpoint I noticed you need to inclulde wql in your query endpoint between api and v1. Yours should look like the following:

https://wd2-impl-services1.workday.com/ccx/api/wql/v1/myredactedorgname/data